# How to limit the result of UNION ALL query?

Tags: mysql, limit, union-all

I have a query like this:

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col1 = ?
union all
select col1, col2 from table2 where col2 = ?
```

Now I need to limit the result of the above query, Now I want to know, if I use `limit` clause after second `select`, then just the result of second `select` will be limited or the result of both `select`?

Anyway, which approach is good for limiting the result of `union all` query?

**One:**

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where col1 = ?
union all
select col1, col2 from table2 where col2 = ?
limit ?,10
```

**Two:**

```
select * from
    (
    select col1, col2 from table1 where col1 = ?
    union all
    select col1, col2 from table2 where col2 = ?
    ) x
limit ?,10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

> To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION
>   result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the
>   ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one.

Hence, you can use:

```
(select col1, col2 from table1 where col1 = ?)
union all
(select col1, col2 from table2 where col2 = ?)
LIMIT ?, 10
```

Using a sub-query should also work, but can't be more efficient in comparison to the above query.

Comment: Are you sure the mean of "parenthesize the individual SELECT statements" is writing each select between paranthesize?

Comment: Yes, it's in the manual. You can check the example cited there.

Comment: @stack This is also from the manual: *A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown.*.

Comment: @stack This means you can omit parentheses if you like. But IMO it's cleaner to use parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

The first is better from a performance perspective.  The second materializes the subquery, which is additional overhead.

Note:  You are using `limit` without an `order by`, so the results may not be consistent from one execution of the query to the next.

You should be using `order by`, which probably makes it irrelevant which version you use (because the `order by` needs to read and write the data anyway).

Comment: @stack . . . The important point is that if you are going to use `limit` then you should use `order by`.

Comment: *"which makes it irrelevant which version you use"*. Honestly I can not understand that. can you tell me how should I use both `limit` and `order by` in my query? tnx